# Why cudaFree doesn't need the address of data structure?

Tags: c, memory-management, cuda

I have a question about the way `cudaFree` works. In the following code, in order to allocate the array on the device, `cudaMalloc` needs the address of the array. That is done by using `&array_d`.

```
int *array_d;
cudaMalloc((void**)&array_d, sizeof(int) * 100);
cudaFree(array_d);
```

Logically, when we want to free the memory, we have to pass the array address to `cudaFree` as well. Otherwise, how does it know which part of the memory has to be freed?

Comment: The first parameter to `cudaMalloc` is an **out** parameter, `cudaMalloc` needs to change the value of your `array_d` variable. The argument to `cudaFree` is an **in** parameter, `cudaFree` can/will **not** change the value of your `array_d` variable to e.g. `NULL`.

Comment: The difference between `cudaMalloc` and `malloc` is that all CUDA runtime API functions all return a `cudaError_t` status. Therefore `cudaMalloc` can't just have the typical `malloc` interface of returning the address of the allocated memory and instead uses an out parameter.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`array_d` is a pointer that is intended to hold the address of the allocated block of memory (containing `int`s in this case).

This address is actually determined by `cudaMalloc`, and therefore you need another level of indirection when calling it.
This is why you pass `&array_d` which is the address of the pointer itself (**not** the address of the pointed memory block), and `cudaMalloc` fills it with the address of the newly allocated block.

`cudaFree` indeed requires this address, to know which memory block to free.
But it does not modify this address. Therefore it is sufficient to pass `array_d` itself (as it holds this address).

This diagram illustrates the relationship between the 3 entities:

```
+----------+      +----------+  
| &array_d |  ->  | array_d  |  ->  memory block on GPU
+----------+      +----------+
```

Note that `array_d` is a pointer holding an address of a memory block that resides in **GPU memory**. But the pointer itself is stored in **host memory** (on the stack in your case).
`&array_d` is the address of that pointer (i.e. an address in **host memory**).

Comment: So in this case, using `cudaFree(array_d)` and `cudaFree(&array_d)` should act the same, apart from compiler logic. Is that right?

Comment: No, because `&array_d` is **not** the address of the allocated block, but rather the address of the pointer. These are 2 separate things, and `cudaFree` requires the address of the block (i.e. `array_d`). If you use a debugger you can easility observe that `array_d` and `&array_d` are 2 different addresses.

Comment: @mahmood added a clarification about the different addresses to my answer.